# A better way to check a child node of a SKNode expanding outside of scene frame

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working on a proof of concept that a **SKNode with a child node** is added to a SKScene. When the child node of the sknode is touched (the green one in figure below), its size will keep growing until it reaches to a pre-determine limit. One of the rule is that when it grows outside of the SKScene frame, it should stop as shown in figure below.

[image]

Below are the code I use to determine whether the child node is growing out of the scene frame.

```
CGFloat minX = node.position.x - (node.childnode.size.width/2);
CGFloat maxX = node.position.x + (node.childnode.size.width/2);
CGFloat minY = node.position.y - (node.childnode.size.height/2);
CGFloat maxY = node.position.y + (node.childnode.size.height/2);

if (minX < CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) || maxX > CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) ||
    minY < CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) || maxY > CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
{
   NSLog(@"the green node expanded out of scene frame");
}
```

Is it a better or simple way doing this. I check the CGRect functions which doesn't seem to have functions that I can use for this. Perhaps I am misunderstand the CGRect function.

Answer (score 1):

`CGRectContainsRect` might help you:

```
if (!CGRectContainsRect(self.frame, node.frame)) {
    NSLog(@"node expanded out of scene frame");
}
```

I assume that `node` is a child for `self`

Comment: Hi,thanks for helping me out. I realize the question I asked miss one of the critical information. Actually, I am the looking for the child node (the green node) of the SKNode (the red node as shown in the updated image) expanding outside of the scene frame not the red SKNode.

Comment: Then change `self.frame` to `self.scene.frame` in my answer

Comment: your solution work when the red node with green node inside is added to the scene initially. Once the size of the green node start increasing, the CGRectContainsRect will return false even the green node still contain by the scene frame.